# How does browser layout adjacent div to a floating div

Tags: css, css-float

I begin to study css recently, and when I learn float, I encounter some problem.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float:

> The float CSS property specifies that an element should be taken from the normal flow and >placed along the left or right side of its container, where text and inline elements will >wrap around it.

But I just wonder, what if a div follow the floating element? So I write a test, and it's not wrap around it, it's overlapped with it, and I really get confused, because somebody told me the floating element won't taken from the normal document flow, and the next div will align left to it if there is enough space.

This is the html and css, note that the right div is not floating, if it is floating, it will behave what I expected, but this is not my question.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Float Layout</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #wrap {
            background: #00c;
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 960px
        }

        #header {
            background: #FF3300;
            width: 100%;
        }

        #mainbody {
            background: #0CF;
            width: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        #footer {
            background: #639;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .left {
            width: 140px;
            height: 200px;
            background: #1f0;
            float: left;
        }

        .right {
            width: 140px;
            height: 500px;
            background: green;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="header">header</div>
    <div id="mainbody">
        <div class="left"><h1>Left</h1></div>
        <div class="right"><h1>Right</h1></div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">footer</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have no enough reputation to post images. The output is that the right div is overlapped by left div, if I replace the right div with a paragraph or h1, it will wrap around the left 
div which is the expected behaviour.

I just wonder why the right div is overlapped by left div which is a floating element? I cannot figure out an explanation how browser handle this. If the floating element is taken from normal document flow, it can explain this behaviour, but this is the truth. So I have no idea on it.

Comment: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/duobedk3/) for the above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever you've quoted from the documentation:

> The float CSS property specifies that an element should be taken from the normal flow and placed along the left or right side of its container, where text and inline elements will wrap around it.

explains this behaviour .

> The output is that the right div is overlapped by left div

- `<div>` is a block element, so it won't wrap around floated elements.
- The floated div is **taken out of normalflow**, hence overlapping the
  `div.right`.

  Which is visible if you increase the width of `.right`.

[image]

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/duobedk3/3/)

> if I replace the right div with a paragraph or h1, it will wrap around the left div which is the expected behaviour.

No. `<p>` and `<h1>` are also block elements just like `<div>`, and hence that is not the expected behaviour. Expected behaviour is that they should behave exactly the same as the div `.right`. Which is happening.

The key thing to note here is that you probably didn't had any text directly inside `.right`, So you thought `<div>` is not wrapping, but `<p>` and `<h1>` are wrapping because you had text inside them which is wrapping:

The elements itself are not wrapping around, (*You just think it is*) Only the text inside them is wrapping around the floated element, Since you've specified `width:140px`, there is not enough space for the text `right` to sit beside the floated div so it breaks down to next line - Which is the expected behaviour.

Same thing will happen if you directly add some text inside `.right` div: it'll wrap around, but this doesn't mean the element itself is wrapping:

The `<block` elements are being overlapped by the floated div and **only the text and inline elements are wrapping around it**, which is what clearly mentioned in the documentation

If you specify enough width, it'll be aligned beside the floated div

[image]

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/duobedk3/4/)

I don't see anything which is unexpected here.

*Side note: "because somebody told me the floating element won't taken from the normal document flow" - I wouldn't believe some guy over the documentation from the guys who makes browsers*

Comment: Thanks T J. I got confused on it for several days, and feel bad to continue to learn css. Your answer make me clear, I always though paragraph or h1 had different behavior, and your answer made me clear that they are all same, just the text in the bock element will be wrapping.

Answer (score 0):

This might help. You should add "float: left;" property for the div which has the class "right". Or if you remove the "width" and "height" properties for both the divs, you can see the difference.